# How to move a shortcut in google drive

Tags: file, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, shortcut

I need to move a shortcut file from one destination to another using google apps script. 
Usually I would move a file or folder like this:

```
function move(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sStamdata = ss.getSheetByName("New");
  var folderOld = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderOldId);
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var id = sStamdata.getRange('D77').getValue();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);

     folderOld.removeFile(file)
     destination.addFile(file)
```

But this doesn't work with shortcuts. Any ideas?

Comment: I could delete the shortcut and then create a new one on the new location... but this seems a bit strange if this is the only solution....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- It seems that in the current stage, the shortcut cannot be moved using Drive service. I think that this might be resolve in the future update.

  - So as the current workaround, in this answer, I would like to propose to use the method of "Files: patch" Drive API v2, because Drive API of Advanced Google services is used.

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you run the script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function move(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sStamdata = ss.getSheetByName("New");
//  var folderOld = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderOldId);
//  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var id = sStamdata.getRange('D77').getValue();
//  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);

  Drive.Files.patch({parents: [{id: folderId}]}, id);  // Added
}
```

- `folderId` is the destination folder ID.
- Please confirm the file ID of the shortcut again.

#### Note:

- For example, when the file ID of the shortcut is confirmed with the shared link using the browser, the file ID is ID of the original file. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Files: patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch)

Comment: as always an answer ready. Thanks! Still a lot to learn for me....

Comment: @Kasper Egelund Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.